# Overwrite uploaded file in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, file-upload

How do I upload a file, move it to a directory and keep the filename while overwriting any existing file? In Zend Framework.

This maintains the tmp filename (like php3382.tmp)

```
$adapter = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
$adapter->setDestination('data/');
$adapter->addFilter('Rename', array(
    'target' => 'data/',
    'overwrite' => true
));

$adapter->receive();
```

and this doesn't overwrite

```
$adapter = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
$adapter->setDestination('data/');
$adapter->receive();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
...

$adapter->addFilter('Rename', array('overwrite'=> true,
                                    'target'=> sprintf('data/%s', 
                                                       $adapter->getFileName()),
                                    ));
$adapter->receive();

....
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why are you splitting by `.`, just to join them again? Also, if there are more than one dot, I think this will fail

Comment: @Znarkus I guest some part of my code in my example is missing (it was taken from some production code) - I might have done something to extension or filename before rewriting the file. And yes, surely there are better ways to get filename and extension. I'll rewrite the example anyways.